# Best way to maintain application state in in React-Native?

Tags: react-native, redux

I worked with react(for web) and used Redux. It seems to me very comfortable. Now I'm working with React-Native and want to maintain somehow my application state. I wanted to use redux, but read in some guides that on React-Native today this is not a very good practice(it's better to use react-contexts). So I'm a little bit confused. Could you explain me what is the better way to maintain\change React-Native application state?

Comment: Feel free to continue using Redux for your React Native projects as well. Personally, I would only use React Context for the AuthState or the LanguageState. However, you can also map the whole thing via Redux.

Comment: Yes. As you can use redux with react, of course, you can use it with react-native.